# Как сделать корректное отображение изображений laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, livewire

При разработке сайта выводится такая таблица:
[image]

Изображения загружены в соответствующие директории. Записи в БД сохраняются. Но не выводятся.
Используется Laravel+Livewire.
Аватарки пользователей (c использованием Jetstream) также не отображаются.
Шаблон вывода:

```
    <table class="min-w-full text-left text-sm font-light">
      <thead class="border-b font-medium dark:border-neutral-500">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-4">Фото</th>
          <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-4">Фамилия и имя</th>
          <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-4"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      @if(count($catalogTeachers))
      @foreach ($catalogTeachers as $catalogTeacher)

        <tr class="border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-neutral-100 dark:border-neutral-500 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600">
          @if(!$catalogTeacher->t_photo)
          <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4"><i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i></td>
          @else
          <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4"><img src="{{$catalogTeacher->t_photo}}" /></td>
          @endif
          <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{{$catalogTeacher->t_name}}</td>
          <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">
             <x-secondary-button wire:click="edit({{$catalogTeacher->id}})" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-pen"></i></x-secondary-button> &nbsp;
             <x-danger-button wire:click="delete({{$catalogTeacher->id}})" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="bi bi-trash2"></i></x-danger-button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        @else
        <tr class="border-b transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-neutral-100 dark:border-neutral-500 dark:hover:bg-neutral-600">
          <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4" colspan=3>Информация отсутствует</td>

        </tr>
        @endif
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Настройки сайта:
```

```
    APP_NAME=Laravel
    APP_ENV=local
    APP_KEY=base64:VVD/*****************************************
    APP_DEBUG=true
    APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Что не так?

Comment: "Соответствующие директории" -- это какие? Попробуйте через хелпер [asset()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-asset), `asset($catalogTeacher->t_photo)`.

Comment: Итоговая ссылка на изображение:http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/teachers/usv6w9QSZFYMGGLVdgECzonjpaULIQWF2Q2RIKB0.png
Директория storage/app/public/teachers/. 
Конфиг:
        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ]
Предлагаемый вариант нового результата не дал.

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` делали?

Comment: Да, конечно. В первую очередь. Не пойму, почему Jetstream тоже аватарку пользователя тоже не выводит...